# Read from the keyboard using pointer to a struct without using dereferencing operator

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dereference

On the example below, why can't I use

```
scanf("%s%d%d", p.name, p.age, p.code);
```

If the variable `p` already has an address, then why do I need to put  `&p->age` instead of `p.age`?
Why do I need to use 'p->name' to read a string from the keyboard instead of `p.name` or `&p->name`? 
If `p->name` is equal `(*p).name`, and `scanf("%s",&variable)` requires an address, how does `(*p).name` work if it's passing to the function `scanf` the value that `p` is pointing to?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct person{
    char name[60];
    int age;
    int code;
};

void printdata(struct person *p){
   printf("%s, %d, %d",p->name, p->age, p->code);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   struct person *p;
   p = (struct person*) malloc(sizeof(struct person));
   scanf("%s%d%d", p->name, &p->age, &p->code);
   printdata(p);
   free(p);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`p` is a pointer to a struct;  `p->age` dereferences that pointer and gets the `age` member, which is an integer, not a pointer; `&p->age` takes the address of `p->age`.  So `p` doesn't have an `age` member, though `*p` does, and you're passing the address of `*p`'s age member to scan.

As for `(*p).name` (i.e. `p->name`), it's because strings are represented as pointers to a character array anyway, so you can pass strings into scanf as before, and it just overwrites the characters within them.  This is dangerous!  So your code will probably buffer overflow and crash if you enter a name longer than 60.

Comment: Correct, but in C, arrays are regions of contiguous memory, and the name associated with that array functions identically to a pointer to the first element of the array.  So for `char x[];`, `x[2] == *(x+2) == 2[x]`

Answer (score 1):

For your first question:

> If the variable `p` already has an address, then why do I need to put `&p->age` instead of `p.age`?

You declare `p` as a pointer

```
struct person *p;
```

Which means that if you want to access for example the age member you have to dereference the pointer first:

```
(*p).age
```

Which is exactly equal to the notation

```
p->age
```

However the `scanf` function, for an integer, [takes a pointer to an int](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/). Since `p->age` points to an int, you have to pass the `age` member by its address. Since `->` operator has [precedence](http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html) over `&` you can write this simply as

```
&p->age
```

The difference with the `name` member of `p` is that since it is declared as an array of `char`'s

```
 p->name
```

is in fact already a pointer, and points to the first element of `name`. Therefore you do not need the `&` operator in front of `p->name` when you pass it to `scanf`